# Using aliases for filenames in AWS CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

A CloudFront stores resized versions of images and serves them to the public. Each image is stored and served in this strict fashion:

`/content/resized/2x/md5_hash_of_image.jpg`

The only variability is `2x` and `md5_hash_of_image`.

Additionally, a query string containing an access key is appended to the request.

However, I would like to serve images in this format:
`/images/2x/md5_hash_of_image/random_friendly_filename.jpg`

The `random_friendly_filename` would be generated on the fly by the server.

Is this possible to do with CloudFront, such as with a custom behavior?

Answer (score 2):

CloudFront has no native capability for this, but it can be accomplished in CloudFront with help from [Lambda@Edge](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-at-the-edge.html) which allows manipulation of CloudFront requests (and responses) in flight using JavaScript.

```
'use strict';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    request.uri = request.uri.replace(/\/[^\/]+\.jpg$/,'.jpg');
    return callback(null, request);
};
```

This takes the uri (the path) and replaces the final `/random-friendly-filename.jpg` with just `.jpg`, thus removing your `random-friendly-filename` and the `/` right before it.

If, for any one specific image, `random-friendly-filename` is always the same, this would be an Origin Request trigger.  If the random friendly name changes even though the base image hash is the same, the you'd need this as a Viewer Request trigger.